# The Here API returns distance, what unit of measurement is the numeric in?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

here API... "distance"... is it meters?  Is it miles?  Feet?

Using the API here.com I am able to get lots of great info, one item is the distance somewhere is from the supplied location in their search api.  The documentation shows the distance as a text example output, but I can't find anywhere that explains what the unit of measurement is.  Maybe all sites use meters and this is just a dumb question?  Maybe I am just not that good at searching through the documentation and it wasn't as hard to find as it seems?  Maybe you have worked with the Here API and just know the answer?

Any help would be appreciated!
-dan

Comment: can you add a link directly to where you at in the documentation thank you

Comment: Its meters. https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-distance.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in their documents, they use meters

> information about each route segment (interconnection) in between two consecutive waypoints including the distance between them in meters and the estimated time in seconds

check it out [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html) press **( cmd + F for mac or ctrl + F for windows  )** and paste the above sentence you should be able to see it.

UPDATE: Check also [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-distance.html) they mention its meters

Answer (score 0):

It is meters. Please use our documentation page to get information on all the request and response fields for any API - developer.here.com/documentation/versions